# Force iOS to return new location?

Tags: ios, swift, location-services

I am making an application that needs the exact location of the user.

Sometimes iOS’ location services do return old location, therefore I do a check on its `timestamp`: if it is older than 60 seconds then it counts as invalid

It can happen two times:

---

- if you return back to the app after a long time, it returns back old location (then after a time it updates to the right loc) but it is invalid data for me.
- if you sit in place for a few minutes, the app detects you are not moving, so it doesn’t update the location: even though it should count as VALID, but my app thinks it’s old:

[image]

Can I force the location services to update the location?

I know there’s the `.requestLocation()` method, but it doesn’t really work..

Whenever this happens that I sit in place and my app thinks it’s invalid, if I switch to the homescreen then I open the app again, it updates the location.

Comment: If you aren't moving then "forcing" a location update won't work; the returned location *is* your location.

Comment: I know it is my location, but ios doesn’t make a difference between two cases: if you sit in place for a few hours, it only generates 1 location; and if you return to the app after a few hours and even though you are not home anymore for example, it will return the last known location that is old and incorrerct.

Comment: right, I understand what you are trying to say, but if you haven't moved how could iOS return a different location?  What location accuracy are you using?